# Populate DBCOMBO in VB6 with recordset

Tags: vb6

I need to populate one dbcombo, i have write this

```
Private Sub cargamunicipios()

   Conexao_Banco

   Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

   SQL = "select código , nome from aux_municipios"

   rs.Open SQL, cn

   DBCombo4.RowSource = rs

End Sub
```

the recorset works fine but have type mistmach , what is the right code to populate a dbcombo???
Thanks Alejnadro

Comment: DBCombo is an old DAO control left in VB6 for VB5 compatibility.  You should use the newer DataCombo instead.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the `Rowsource` property is supposed to point to the Name of Data Control that's used as a source of items for the list portion of the DBcombo control.

You should be assigning your recordset to the Data Control at design time - and make sure your DBCombo's rowsource property to that Data Control - but it is not available at run time.

So instead of:

`DBCombo4.RowSource = rs`

You should use assign the recordset to the **Recordsource** property of your datacontrol (where ADODC is name of your Data Control):

```
ADODC.RecordSource = rs
```

And in Design View - set the DB Combo's Rowsource to your Data Control:

```
DBCombo4.RowSource = ADODC
```

Answer (score 1):

DBcombo controls (data bound) only works with ADO data controls, instead use DataCombo (data list) below a sample code..

```
Private Sub cargamunicipios()
    Conexao_Banco
        Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
        SQL = "select código , nome from aux_municipios"
    rs.Open SQL, cn
    With DBCombo4
        .RowSource = rs
        .ListField = "código"
        .BoundColumn = "name"
    End With
End Sub
```